# Actual page number (and total number of pages) in the handout

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I am trying to print out page number/total number of pages in the handout that I get from this code: This is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=10mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First}
\begin{itemize}
\item check1
\item check 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to modify the code in a way that I can add (ideally) header and footer (OR at least page #/# of pages) in the right bottum corner. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to print page number on the page or frame number on each frame ?

Comment: Thanks to @Gonzalo Medina: he answered the question in this post: [Header and Footer in handout using pgfpages][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83257/header-and-footer-in-handout-using-pgfpages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the package pdfpages that I used in order to do handouts.

First, run your beamer document with `handout` option and call it `prep_handout.pdf` for example. Then run this tex file to create the handout with several frames per page. Here I used `fancyhdr` in order to manage the headers/footers.

Although you must create a new tex file, `pdfpages` package and the `includepdf` command give you plenty of options. Here the key option is the `pagecommand` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm, left=1cm, bottom=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\sffamily left header}
\fancyhead[R]{right header}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=44-55,nup=2x2,frame=true,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
            noautoscale=true,scale=0.9,delta=5mm 5mm]{prep_handout.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Even though I was hoping I could do it using pgfpages, nevertheless, this solution worked very well. Thank you!

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, do you think it is possible to do the same thing using pgfpages? Thanks

Comment: I am so sorry for multiple comments. What happens is that, by using the suggested the suggested method, I loose my automatic bookmarks in the pdf file of the handouts...

Comment: Yes, as you include the pdf you loose hyppertex information. I do not know pgfpages ... sorry. However, using pgfpages you will probably keep your hypperlinks.